# 'Median scaling' and 'Normalization by median deviation'

Tags: dataset, normalization, multidimensional-scaling

Here I am providing a paragraph from a paper,

"This “median” scaling is performed by subtracting the median of the variable’s distribution in the data sample and normalising by the median deviation."

Could anyone throw some light on the same?
What exactly is median scaling and median deviation and how these both are used in the normalisation as mentioned above?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 5):

Normalization typically seeks to produce data with a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1, so we transform each data point $x_i$ by $z_i=(x_i-\bar{x})/s$. This will guarantee that the transformed $Z$ variable has a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1, except for (maybe) some numerical issues on a computer.

However, perhaps we want our transformed variable to have a median of 0 and median deviation of 1. The above formula will not guarantee that, but we can follow the same idea by subtracting the median of $X$ and then dividing by the median deviation.

Such a process will guarantee that the transformed variable has a median of 0 and median deviation of 1.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Could you elaborate this by an example with numbers? How to calculate median deviation?

Comment: The paper should define or reference their definition of median deviation. I could see a couple of definitions. One is  $median\{ \vert x_i - median(x) \vert  \}$. Another is $median\{ \vert x_i - \bar{x} \vert  \}$. Finally, I could imagine using $median\{(x_i - \bar{x})^2\}$. I think the first is the most likely, but they should define their terms.